# Analyzing the push-pull output CMOS stage

Tags: mosfet, cmos

[image]

My problem is, when V2 is 5V, M2 will cutoff obviously. So now if I measure the open-circuit output, which result will I get? Since the source of M1(NMOS) is floating without connecting to anything, I don't know how to analyze the state of M1(NMOS).
But the simulation from LTspice shows that, when V2 is 5V, output is also 5V. This is what confusing me. It seems like even source of M1(NMOS) is floating, the NMOS is working somehow in the triode region or saturation region.
Can someone give me a valid explanation of method of analyzing? Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't you connect the substrate connections?

Comment: @Huisman I have edited. Thanks

Comment: Your circuit is an NMOS source follower and a PMOS source follower in parallel. A source follower (or common drain circuit) follows the input signal. When V2 (input) is 5 V then you will only see 5 V at the output if you **do not load the output at all**. In that case the simulator's result can be **inaccurate** as the real voltage relies on small leakage currents etc. because both transistors will be **off**. If you add a load resistor to ground then Vout will drop to about 4 V or less. But before that I suggest that you **study how the common drain circuit works**, so with only an NMOS.

Comment: You also might want to read: http://home.iitk.ac.in/~baquer/L20_Class_AB.pdf

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Okay, you mean that I cannot rely on simulator in this case? Because both are off, if V2 is 5V

Comment: *you mean that I cannot rely on simulator in this case?* Yes, in the real world such a circuit will be unable to reach 5 V at the output, how can it as the NMOS is off? I suspect that the MOSFET model you're using isn't accurate enough for this and is giving you unrealistic results. Add a 10 Mohm resistor between output and ground, now what output voltage do you get?

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I have add a 10Kohm resistor between output and ground, now I get about 1.35V.

Comment: 1.35 V with 10 k ohm load makes more sense. Can you explain why you get only 1.35 V now?

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I think the reason being that the current is too big. However, can you mathematically show that when V2=5V, the NMOS will turn on? If I want to know if it is on or off, I need to know output voltage (source voltage), but in order to calculate output voltage I need to know drain current. But if I want to know drain current, I need to know output voltage. It is like a ring.. How can I solve the output voltage?

Comment: 1.35 V over 10 kohm that means 135 uA is flowing. For the 135 uA the NMOS appears to need a Vgs = 5 V - 1.35V = 3.65 V. If you increase the W/L of the NMOS then Vgs will become smaller. For an extremely large W/L you get the lowest Vgs possible to turn on the NMOS. What value is that? Vgs = ...V That's the highest output voltage you can ever get with this circuit.

Comment: I would design this in this way: What is the lowest output load that we need to drive? What does the output voltage need to be. Then I can calculate the maximum current. Then I change the W/L of the NMOS to meet the requirements. Vout cannot be much more than 3.5 V as there needs to be some "room" for Vgs. Vgs cannot be zero!